Unauthorized - Settings Cookies as Bearer Token Nextjs
I'm using Next.js pages router. I set the access_token in the cookies this way. The access_token is being set correctly but why do I still get "Unauthorized"?
My login API route:
import { api } from "../axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export async function login(data: SignInFormData) {
  try {
    const response = await api.post("/auth/login", data);

    const token = response.data.access_token;
    Cookies.set("jwt", token, {
      expires: 100
    });

    return response.data;
  }
}

This is my Axios config:
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  timeout: 1000,
  maxRate: 1000,
});

// Request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const accessToken = Cookies.get("jwt");

    if (accessToken) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);


do you have reproducible code sample

Is your be side checking auth from header or cookies? and why if you use author header why not simply set token to local storage but need to set in cookies?
